# How to convert pandas object to either currency or int?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working on an EDA side project with the Unicorn dataset from maven analytics. There is a column VALUATION with entries like $1B,$150M, etc. I want to convert it to either a currency or int format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting millions and billion to a number or integer in a Python column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784313/converting-millions-and-billion-to-a-number-or-integer-in-a-python-column)

Comment: Hello,I tried to use the code but it say as TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.